# How can I start an interactive console for Perl?

Tags: perl, console, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

How can I start an interactive console for Perl, similar to the `irb` command for Ruby or `python` for Python?

Answer (score 345, accepted):

You can use the perl debugger on a trivial program, like so:

```
perl -de1
```

This command will start the Perl debugger (`-d`) on expression `1` (`-e1`), because the debugger wants something to debug (usually a file containing Perl code).
The command could be written as `perl -d -e 1` as well.

Alternatively there's [*Alexis Sukrieh*'s Perl Console](http://search.cpan.org/%7Esukria/perlconsole-0.4/perlconsole) application, but I haven't used it.

Comment: If you want something minimimaly usable consider to add [rlwrap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap) `$ rlwrap perl -d -e 1` You would get history and a consistent prompt

Comment: `control`+`L` doesn't work under this command interface, how should I refresh the screen?

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight: [Ján Sáreník's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22840242/45375) seems to provide the best almost-out-of-the-box solution (you may have to install `rlwrap`).
All third-party REPL/console solutions, including `perlconsole`, are cumbersome to install and often have more limitations.

Comment: Unfortunately, `perl -de1` doesn't seem to support `my` variables, and hashes don't work either, for some reason…

Comment: `perlconsole` doesn't suffer from these problems.

Answer (score 67):

Not only did Matt Trout write an article about a REPL, he actually wrote one - [Devel::REPL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-REPL)

I've used it a bit and it works fairly well, and it's under active development.

BTW, I have no idea why someone modded down the person who mentioned using "perl -e" from the console. This isn't really a REPL, true, but it's fantastically useful, and I use it all the time.

Comment: I think it was assumed I didn't understand the question.  I guess I'll edit it a bit. ;-)

Comment: As of mid-2015: Simply running `[sudo] cpan Devel::REPL` didn't work for me, neither on OSX 10.10 (Perl 5.18.2) nor on Ubuntu 14.04 (Perl 5.18.2): I get runtime errors complaining about missing modules; installed one, then gave up after another missing module was reported.

Comment: @mklement0 There's a cpan setting to download and build prerequisite modules automatically. You might need to turn that setting on. Alternatively, the zero-config [cpanminus](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus) application may be a better option.

Comment: @Starfish: Thanks; to save future readers time (since it sounds like the answer may be short): how do you turn this setting on?

Comment: By the way, Matt Trout, the `re.pl` author, wrote an article listing several alternatives, and he himself suggests using `reply` instead of `re.pl`: http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-17/

Comment: Installed this on Centos 6 / Perl 5.10 just now - it dragged in 88 new/updated modules! Seems like a lot for a REPL ...

Answer (score 45):

If you want history, use [rlwrap](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rlwrap). This could be your `~/bin/ips` for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 'This is Interactive Perl shell'
rlwrap -A -pgreen -S"perl> " perl -wnE'say eval()//$@'
```

And this is how it looks like:

```
$ ips
This is Interactive Perl shell
perl> 2**128
3.40282366920938e+38
perl>
```

Comment: Kudos for wrapping it up nicely - readline support is not only needed for history, but also for editing the command line. With the exception of multi-line support, this works well; here's an alias version as an alternative: `alias iperl='rlwrap -A -S "perl> " perl -wnE '\''say eval()//$@'\'`. OSX users can install `rlwrap` via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) with `brew install rlwrap`.

Comment: Here is a version that gives a nice output when the expression evaluates to a list or a reference: `rlwrap -A -pgreen -S'perl> ' perl -MData::Dumper -wnE'say Dumper[eval()]//$@'`

Answer (score 40):

I wrote a script I call "psh":

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my $result = eval;
  print "$_ = $result\n";
}
```

Whatever you type in, it evaluates in Perl:

```
> gmtime(2**30)
gmtime(2**30) = Sat Jan 10 13:37:04 2004

> $x = 'foo'
$x = 'foo' = foo

> $x =~ s/o/a/g
$x =~ s/o/a/g = 2

> $x
$x = faa
```

Comment: Does this work for one liners only or can handle multiline Perl code like conditional branching, loops, nested statements?

Answer (score 23):

I think you're asking about a REPL (Read, Evaluate, Print, Loop) interface to perl. There are a few ways to do this:

- Matt Trout has [an article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100921094613/http://chainsawblues.vox.com/library/post/a-perl-read-excute-print-loop-repl.html) that describes how to write one
- Adriano Ferreira [has described some options](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905151804/http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/articlea9a7.html?sid=07/08/30/1729255)
- and finally, you can hop on IRC at irc.perl.org and try out one of the eval bots in many of the popular channels. They will evaluate chunks of perl that you pass to them.

Comment: Matt Trout's article has been down since some years ago, you can find it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20100212100032/http://chainsawblues.vox.com/library/post/a-perl-read-excute-print-loop-repl.html

Comment: Matt Trout now has a far more up to date list of REPLs he recommends: http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-17/

Answer (score 21):

I use the command line as a console:

```
$ perl -e 'print "JAPH\n"'
```

Then I can use my *bash* history to get back old commands.  This does not preserve state, however.

This form is most useful when you want to test "one little thing" (like when answering Perl questions).  Often, I find these commands get scraped verbatim into a shell script  or makefile.

Comment: With some shells, like `fish`, you don't even need the `\n`.

Answer (score 20):

There isn't an interactive console for Perl built in like Python does.  You can however use the Perl Debugger to do debugging related things.  You turn it on with the -d option, but you might want to check out 'man perldebug' to learn about it.

After a bit of googling, there is a separate project that implements a Perl console which you can find at
[Perl Console - Perl code interactive evaluator with completion](https://web.archive.org/web/20170726140417/http://www.sukria.net/perlconsole.html).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 19):

There are two popular Perl REPLs.

1. [Devel::REPL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL) is great.
2. But IMO [Reply](https://metacpan.org/pod/Reply) is better.

For `reply` just run it as a command. The module install the `reply` script. If you had installed the module and you don't have the command, check your `PATH` variable.

```
$ reply --help
reply [-lb] [-I dir] [-M mod] [--version] [--help] [--cfg file]
```

Comment: +1 for recommending Reply. Devel::REPL's author himself recommended Reply over its own solution when I ask about a good Perl REPL (console) on IRC. Reply also comes with auto-completion that is very handy for inspecting an object's available methods and attributes. I could install Reply on Ubuntu with the following command: `sudo apt-get install libreply-perl`. Then it can be run simply typing `reply` in a terminal.

Comment: How do you install amd run Reply? Neither the Metacpan, nor the Github page provides instructions.

Comment: Check the edited answer. `reply`

Answer (score 15):

You can always just drop into the built-in debugger and run commands from there.

```
   perl -d -e 1
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73703/6607497

Answer (score 15):

I've created [`perli`](https://github.com/mklement0/perli), a **Perl REPL** that runs on **Linux, macOS, and Windows**.

Its focus is automatic result printing, convenient documentation lookups, and easy
inspection of regular-expression matches.
You can see screenshots [here](https://github.com/mklement0/perli#examples).

It works **stand-alone** (has no dependencies other than Perl itself), but **installation of [`rlwrap`](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) is strongly recommended** so as to support command-line editing, persistent command history, and tab-completion - read more [here](https://github.com/mklement0/perli#supported-platforms-and-prerequisites).

**Installation**

- If you happen to have Node.js installed:

  ```
  npm install -g perli
  ```
- Otherwise:

  - *Unix*-like platforms: Download [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/perli/stable/bin/perli) as `perli` to a folder in your system's path and make it executable with `chmod +x`.
  - *Windows*: Download the [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/perli/stable/bin/perli) as `perli.pl` (note the `.pl` extension) to a folder in your system's path.
    If you don't mind invoking Perli as `perli.pl`, you're all set.
    Otherwise, create a batch file named `perli.cmd` in the same folder with the following content: `@%~dpn.pl %*`; this enables invocation as just `perli`.

Comment: I like it can launch `perldoc` from `perli` REPL like `'someCommand ?'` . Looks like it hasn't been updated for a while though, are you still maintaining perli?

Comment: @sdkks: If you find a problem, do [report it on GitHub](https://github.com/mklement0/perli/issues) and I'll try to fix it. `perli` hasn't been updated in a while, because in my personal use I haven't come across any issues, and few other people seem to use it, but, as far as I know, it still works as advertised.

Comment: I reported an issue and @mklement0 had it fixed and a new version released in less than 24 hours, FWIW. :)

Answer (score 9):

Perl doesn't have a console but the debugger can be used as one. At a command prompt, type `perl -de 1`. (The value "1" doesn't matter, it's just a valid statement that does nothing.)

There are also a couple of options for a Perl shell:
[Archived "perlfaq3" page which contain question "Is there Perl Shell?"](https://web.archive.org/web/20120522111043/http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#Is-there-a-Perl-shell%3f)

For more information read [perlfaq3](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq3) (current version).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73703/6607497

Answer (score 7):

`perl -d` is your friend:

```
% perl -de 0
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73703/6607497

Answer (score 7):

re.pl from Devel::REPL

Answer (score 7):

I always did:

```
rlwrap perl -wlne'eval;print$@if$@'
```

With 5.10, I've switched to:

```
rlwrap perl -wnE'say eval()//$@'
```

(rlwrap is optional)

Answer (score 6):

You could look into psh here: http://gnp.github.io/psh/

It's a full on shell (you can use it in replacement of bash for example), but uses perl syntax.. so you can create methods on the fly etc.

Answer (score 5):

Read-eval-print loop:

```
$ perl -e'while(<>){print eval,"\n"}'
```

Answer (score 5):

<sup>Update: I've since created a downloadable REPL - see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32798002/45375).</sup>

With the benefit of hindsight:

- The **third-party solutions** mentioned among the existing answers are either **cumbersome to install and/or do not work without non-trivial, non-obvious additional steps** - some solutions appear to be at least half-abandoned.
- **A usable REPL needs the readline library for command-line-editing keyboard support and history support** - ensuring this is a trouble spot for many third-party solutions.
- If you install CLI **`rlwrap`, which provides readline support to any command, you can combine it with a simple Perl command to create a usable REPL**, and thus make do without third-party REPL solutions.

  - On OSX, you can install `rlwrap` via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) with `brew install rlwrap`.
  - Linux distros should offer `rlwrap` via their respective package managers; e.g., on Ubuntu, use `sudo apt-get install rlwrap`.
  - **See [Ján Sáreník's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22840242/45375) for said combination of `rlwrap` and a Perl command.**

---

**What you do NOT get** with Ján's answer:

- auto-completion
- ability to enter multi-line statements

The only third-party solution that offers these (with non-trivial installation + additional, non-obvious steps), is **[psh](https://github.com/gnp/psh)**, but:

- it hasn't seen activity in around 2.5 years
- its focus is different in that it aims to be a full-fledged *shell replacement*, and thus works like a traditional shell, which means that it doesn't automatically evaluate a command as a *Perl* statement, and requires an explicit output command such as `print` to print the result of an expression.

---

[Ján Sáreník's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22840242/45375) can be improved in one way:

- By default, it **prints arrays/lists/hashtables as *scalars***, i.e., only prints their *element count*, whereas it would be handy to enumerate their elements instead.

If you install the **`Data::Printer`** module with `[sudo] cpan Data::Printer` as a one-time operation, you can load it into the REPL for use of the **`p()` function, to which you can pass lists/arrays/hashtables for enumeration.**

Here's an **alias named `iperl` with readline and `Data::Printer` support**, which can you put in your POSIX-like shell's initialization file (e.g., `~/.bashrc`):

```
alias iperl='rlwrap -A -S "iperl> " perl -MData::Printer -wnE '\''BEGIN { say "# Use `p @<arrayOrList>` or `p %<hashTable>` to print arrays/lists/hashtables; e.g.: `p %ENV`"; } say eval()//$@'\'
```

E.g., you can then do the following to print all environment variables via hashtable `%ENV`:

```
$ iperl        # start the REPL
iperl> p %ENV  # print key-value pairs in hashtable %ENV
```

As with Ján's answer, the *scalar* result of an expression is *automatically* printed; e.g.:

```
iperl> 22 / 7  # automatically print scalar result of expression: 3.14285714285714
```

Answer (score 5):

Matt Trout's [overview](http://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/mstpan-17/) lists five choices, from `perl -de 0` onwards, and he recommends [`Reply`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Reply), if extensibility via plugins is important, or `tinyrepl` from [`Eval::WithLexicals`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Eval::WithLexicals), for a minimal, pure-perl solution that includes readline support and lexical persistence.

If you use the GNU Guix package manager, you can enter a working environment for tinyrepl with:

```
$ guix shell perl perl-eval-withlexicals perl-term-readline-gnu
[env]$ tinyrepl
re.pl$ 'hello world!'
"hello world!"
```

Answer (score 4):

Under Debian/Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libdevel-repl-perl
$ re.pl

$ sudo apt-get install libapp-repl-perl
$ iperl
```

Answer (score 2):

See also [Stylish REPL (for GNU Emacs)](https://web.archive.org/web/20090109221511/http://blog.jrock.us/articles/Stylish%20REPL.pod)

Answer (score 1):

Also look for ptkdb on CPAN:
http://search.cpan.org/search?query=ptkdb&mode=all

Answer (score 1):

Sepia and PDE have also own REPLs (for GNU Emacs).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it online (like many things in life) here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org-babel` in `emacs`; Open an `org-mode` file, i.e., `tmp.org`, and then you can do:

```
#+begin_src perl :results output
@a = (1,5,9);
print ((join ", ", @a) . "\n");
$b = scalar @a;
print "$#a, $b\n";
print "$#a, " . @a . "\n";
print join ", ", 1..$#a; print "\n";
print join ", ", @a[0..$#a]
#+end_src
```

Pressing `CTRL-c CTRL-c` evals the block:

```
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
1, 5, 9
2, 3
2, 3
1, 2
1, 5, 9
#+end_example
```

I am not sure what emacs config this needs to work, but I think you can just install https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs and enable its `perl` and `org-mode` modules.