# How can I start an interactive console for VBS?

Tags: vbscript, console, interpreter, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

Very similar to this question:

[How can I start an interactive console for Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73667/how-can-i-start-an-interactive-console-for-perl)

I just want to be able to start entering VBS statements, one at a time, and have them evaluated straight away, like Python's IDLE.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote [this](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vbsh.shtml) a couple years ago. It's based on [this blog post](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2004/04/01/interactiveVbscript)  (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20040405070027/http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2004/04/01/interactiveVbscript)), but with a couple enhancements. Essentially it's a REPL (Read, Execute, Print, Loop) using the [`Execute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03t418d2.aspx) statement:

```
If Not LCase( Right( WScript.FullName, 12 ) ) = "\cscript.exe" Then
    For Each Arg In WScript.Arguments
        If InStr( Arg, " " ) Then Arg = """" & Arg & """"
        Str = Str & " " & Arg
    Next
    WshShell.Run "cscript """ & WScript.ScriptFullName & """" & Str, 1
    WScript.Quit
End If

Do While True
    WScript.StdOut.Write(">>> ")

    line = Trim(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine)

    If LCase(line) = "exit" Then Exit Do

    On Error Resume Next
    Execute line
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.StdErr.WriteLine Err.Description
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
Loop
```

I usually start it with a batch file of the same name (i.e. "vbs.vbs" and "vbs.bat"), like this:

```
@cscript.exe //NoLogo %~dpn0.vbs
```

Comment: I'd add `If Left(line, 2) = "? " Then line = Replace(line, "? ", "WScript.Echo ", 1, 1)`, to mimic what the VBA IDE does.

Comment: Thanks for catching the syntax error. The code sample is just a minimalistic core implementation to demonstrate how the thing works in general. My real code (link at the beginning of my answer) is a little more elaborate and uses `?` for opening the VBScript help file at the given keyword.

Comment: I wished it continued lines with "_".

Comment: @js2010 The real thing does.

Comment: This looks great for one-liners. I'm unable to create Subs and Functions. Is that a limitation of this REPL? I really like this answer, especially with @Tomalak 's extra.

Comment: @Daniel'Dang'Griffith You can separate multiple statements with `:`, like `Sub Test() : Msgbox("Hey") : End Sub` but of course this gets unwieldy quickly. For more complex behaviour you'd have to move away from `WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()`, for example to a loop over `WScript.StdIn.Read(1)` that keeps reading characters until it finds a special "now run all this" keyword. Certainly doable if you put your mind to it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to make a debugger (`cscript //X your.vbs`) work for you, or to start a project of your own - perhaps based on [these (first 3?) proposals](https://web.archive.org/web/20110104151814/http://www.visualbasicscript.com/WeeklyMonthly-Challenge-m47585-p3.aspx)