# Perl - How do you type/execute/run Perl statements directly in the Perl shell/interpreter?

Tags: perl, command-line-interface

How do you type and then (*execute/run*) Perl statements directly in the Perl shell/interpreter?

First, I'm on Windows...  and I have Strawberry Perl (v5.32.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread installed.

So, if I type at the command line, just :

```
perl
```

... it appears to enter into a Perl "shell/interpreter", but if I enter some Perl statements :

```
my $greeting = "Hello World :-)\n";
print($greeting);
```

... how do I make it then "execute/run" those two statements?

If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>, then it just says: `Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)`

If it matters, the reason I'd like to do this is so that I can just test Perl language as I'm learning about Perl.

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Z`, it should be end-of-file on MSWin (`Ctrl+D` on *nix). Or enter `__END__`.

Comment: There's a `re.pl` script that comes with [Devel::REPL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel%3A%3AREPL) that you might find handy.

Comment: Keep in mind that `perl` is not a REPL. It's the Perl compiler, so it expects a full program. You can't run line by line. The easiest way to run stuff on the fly is to use an IDE and to configure a shortcut to run your current file. On VSCode I use [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). Or you can save, `Alt+Tab` and `up` and `enter` to rerun in the terminal.

Comment: You can just run perl code as a one-liner: `perl -we"print qq(Hello world!\n)"`

Comment: In Windows cmd, you need to use double quotes to surround the code. Hence, you need to use `qq()` for double quoted strings. I believe people rarely use the shell interpretation, like the one people use for python for example.

Comment: Thanks @JimDavis && simbabque for your suggestions, good ideas for alternatives.

Comment: @TLP I needed multiple statements, but now I know how to do a one-liner, thanks.

Comment: @George2.0Hope You can do multiple statements in one-liners.... You can do as many commands as you can with a program file, you just put them on "one line" because you can do that in Perl. Heck, you can even add line endings with backslash in some shells.

Comment: `perl -we"print qq(Hello world\n); print qq(Hey look, you can do multiple statements!\n); for (0 .. 10) { print }"`

Comment: @choroba if you convert your comment to an answer, and make one small change (*when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>, it puts `^Z` in the terminal window, you still need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after it ... also `__END__`<kbd>Enter</kbd> works as well*), I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (final <kbd>Enter</kbd> still needed) corresponds to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> on *nix and means *End of file*. You can also enter `__END__`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a REPL using the debugger:

```
$ perl -d -e 1

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.49
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(-e:1):   1
  DB<1> x "blah" x 5
0  'blahblahblahblahblah'
```

Use `x expression` or `p expression` to evaluate an expression and display the result in different ways.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what's asked. If so, they should consult [How can I start an interactive console for Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73703/589924)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a so-called one-liner (*) and type code directly into the shell. It is the idiomatic way to test Perl statements:

```
perl -we"my $greeting = qq(Hello World :-)\n); print $greeting;"
```

Note that in Windows cmd shell you need to surround the code with double quotes, hence you use `qq()` for double quoted strings inside the code.

I always use the `-l` switch on the command line, so that I don't have to add line endings to print:

```
perl -lwe"my $greeting = 'Hello World :-)'; print $greeting;"
```

You may also consider using `-E` and `say`, which adds a newline as well:

```
perl -wE"say 'Hello world :-)'"
```

You can even use multiple lines, in some shells, though not in Windows.

(*) = Don't be fooled by the word "one-liner". That is not the number of statements you can use, that is just a way to name a statement that is on "one line". In Perl you can add multiple statements on a single line if you like.

Comment: ...or you can even use multiples lines if you want, should the shell allow it. (cmd doesn't)